# How to communicate Vtiger 6 and the webservices

Tags: vtiger

is there any webservice lib for the 6.0.0 version ?
like the the vtiger Web services Client library vtwsclib-1.4 ? does that works on version 6.0.0 too

Comment: At least there is a `webservice.php` that looks like an entry point to me.

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation, [this](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) is the page containing REST API documentation for Third-Party developers, and it still links to the download of the vtwsclib 1.4 at the [vTiger Forge page](http://forge.vtiger.com/projects/vtwsclib). Looks like it is still the recommended library for version 6.0.

Extra personal notes: The file webservice.php in vTiger 5.4.0 (located in the root folder) reports the same API version (0.22) as the one in vTiger 6.0.0. 
My small sample application that I use for tests, which is compliant with vtwsclib1.4, that performs some operations on the vTiger webservice still works on vTiger 6.0.0.